# Can I restore a backup file from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server Express edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database in SQL Server - how can I make a backup for a specific database  and restore it onto another machine that has SQL Server Express edition?

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the database and task --> backup.
The version of the SQL Server must be the same, the edition does not matter by restoring database.

Comment: And the **database size** cannot exceed **4 GB** (for SQL Server 2008 Express) - later versions support up to **10 GB**)

Comment: And the version of SQL Server doesn't have to be the same. It may be a higher version.

Comment: Note that you also cannot restore a database with Enterprise-only features to a lower edition (ie- Express, Standard).